# Only skype has no title bar in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, skype, titlebar

I am using Lubuntu 13.10. I am facing a problem with Skype, it has no title bar, so I can't move it.

Here you can see the screen shot

[image]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution image.</sup>

Comment: Use Alt+F7 to move it.

Comment: not worked, and not works in other windows

Comment: I've searched for it: There isn't such and possibility in LXDE.

Comment: so, how to be. i think skype had had title bar, but then it lost.

Comment: Close skype, then open it.

Comment: i did it million times.

Comment: oh, I found it, just clicked mouse right button on the top right of the Skype window when mouse cursor shows resize icon, in context menu it has move function

Comment: @NadirNovruzov Congratulations on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? :) You know, you can [answer and even accept your own answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the right mouse button on the top right of the Skype window when the mouse cursor shows the resize icon. In the context menu there is a move function.

Answer (score 2):

So, I know this question is old but this issue keeps happening now on Lubuntu 14.04, and I just found a solution by accident, so I wanna share.

To anyone who faces this on Lubuntu, go to skype's **Options > IM tab > Uncheck "Use Default View"** and the chat windows you had open will probably close themselves. If you open them again they will be movable and have a title bar now.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + left mouse button and drag also works too. Because it was in the top-left of the screen, I assumed the window decorations weren't being drawn, didn't think it could be moved!

Comment: Please elaborate - an answer should not rely on another answer but stand as it's own.